# Play Framework: Created WAR file is not zipped up

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using Play Framework 1.2.5.3.  When I run the WAR command on my project, what I get is a directory with the .war extension.  Inside the directory is a WEB-INF dir and the rest of my project inside that.

Isn't the play war command supposed to package the project as a standard WAR jar for deployment on a web server?   What am i missing?

Comment: If you don't like that, you can always remove the `.war` from the directory, then make a ZIP archive of it and rename it from `mycoolapp.zip` to `mycoolapp.war`.

Comment: @Carsten - Thanks!  Man, you gotta hit me w/ all these play questions as of late. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework creates the war in the exploded directory format and not as a compressed file. It is mentioned as part of the  [play framework deployment documentatio](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/deployment)n:

> Please note that your application server must support deployment of
>   exploded WAR files.

Comment: Hmm... i even read that line.  That's some horrible wording IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I know some containers (like `JBoss`) allow you to deploy directories like this in the same way as an archive, with the `.war` extension. It's called an "exploded artefact/deployment".

[Link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExplodedDeployment)